# ios use regex to find ID in html

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsregularexpression

Im using NSRegularExpression to find the occurrences of an ID with 40 characters in a HTML

here my code:

```
 - (NSString *)stripOutHttp:(NSString *)string {

NSLog(@"the page content :: %@", string);

// Setup an NSError object to catch any failures
NSError *error = NULL;

// create the NSRegularExpression object and initialize it with a pattern
// the pattern will match any http or https url, with option case insensitive

//search for:: <input type="hidden" name="XID" value="f3f3fbafe552358d9312d1fe30670add09adc36c" />


NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"XID\" value\"?" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error]; // ultimo funcional



// try /\b([a-f0-9]{40})\b/


// create an NSRange object using our regex object for the first match in the string 

NSRange rangeOfFirstMatch = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

// check that our NSRange object is not equal to range of NSNotFound

if (!NSEqualRanges(rangeOfFirstMatch, NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0))) {
    // Since we know that we found a match, get the substring from the parent string by using our NSRange object

    NSString *substringForFirstMatch = [string substringWithRange:rangeOfFirstMatch];

    NSLog(@"Extracted data : %@",substringForFirstMatch);

    // return the matching string
    return substringForFirstMatch;
}

return NULL;
  }
```

So with my current regex:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"XID\" value\"?" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error]; // ultimo funcional
```

I get part of what I need:

```
Extracted data : <input type="hidden" name="XID" value
```

Now how do I get the response for any 40 characters value?

I have tried with

```
// try /\b([a-f0-9]{40})\b/
```

But dont seem to understand how to use it yet,

this is the kind of response im after::

```
<input type="hidden" name="XID" value="f3f3fbafe552358d9312d1fe30670add09adc36c" />
```

thanks a lot

Comment: Parse the HTML with an HTML parser. It's going to be much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expressions

```
 <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"XID\" value=\"([a-f0-9]{40})\"[\s]*/>
```

should match your input string

I don't think it's the best idea though, for one thing, you use a lot of spaces where arbitrary whitespace is possible too.
I'd look into html parser libraries if I were you.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider parsing the whole thing with a html or xml parser (like Blender said) but for now, the answer to your question would be the following:

```
 "<[^>]*id=DIVNAME.*?>(.*?)/>"
```